# how to get last query in codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, query-builder, codeigniter-4

This is my current code:

```php
public function index()
{
    $tbl = 'm_trx';
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $builder = $db->table($tbl);
    
    $data = [];

    $cols = "{$tbl}.*";
    $builder->select($cols);

    $data = $builder->get()->getResult();
    $asd = [
        'message' => $builder->getLastQuery(),
        'data' => $data,
    ];
    return $this->respond($asd);
}
```

but it returns error

`"message": "Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\\Database\\MySQLi\\Builder::getLastQuery()",`

if I changed `$builder->getLastQuery()` into `$builder->db->getLastQuery()` it returns this error instead

`"message": "Cannot access protected property CodeIgniter\\Database\\MySQLi\\Builder::$db",`

Comment: You can always extend builder and expose $db if needed or use Reflection

Comment: what do you mean by "extend builder and expose $db"? will I get the last query with that method? if yes, how do I do that? and what is Reflection? I'm currently debugging the code using Postman..

Comment: If $db is protected then your subclass can access it so you can i. E. make getter, add helper method using it or whatever. If it is private, then use Reflection

Comment: `$db->getLastQuery()`

Comment: where is `$tbl` defined?

Comment: @Vickel sorry I forgot to add the variable declaration. just edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to pass `$db` and not `$builder->db`

Try this

```
$db->getLastQuery()
```